# Cannot integrate Alamofire on Jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, jenkins, alamofire

I'm trying to perform CI on a Swift project that has Alamofire integrated into it (as a pod). However, I'm getting the following errors when built on the Jenkins server:

```
The following build commands failed:
CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/tsd007/.jenkins/jobs/HelloWorldIOS/workspace/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift
CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/tsd007/.jenkins/jobs/HelloWorldIOS/workspace/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Download.swift
CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/tsd007/.jenkins/jobs/HelloWorldIOS/workspace/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Error.swift
CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/tsd007/.jenkins/jobs/HelloWorldIOS/workspace/Pods/Alamofire/Source/Manager.swift
CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
```

However when I built it locally in the IDE (XCode), everything is fine. Anybody got this issue before? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a well-documented issue. One [very close example](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/365) has been closed due to the issue seemingly being fixed as of Xcode (6.2).

It appears this newer version of Xcode (or any version thereafter) should allow your code to be built from the command line and/or from Jenkins because of differences in what Xcode produces.